# Microsoft Cognitive Services Face API Error for Java Create a Person Group

Tags: java, azure-cognitive-services

This code for Create a Person Group with Java.

```
import java.net.URI;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class JavaSample 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

        try
        {
            URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder("https://api.projectoxford.ai/face/v1.0/persongroups/personGroupId");


            URI uri = builder.build();
            HttpPut request = new HttpPut(uri);
            request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.setHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "mysubscriptionkey");


            // Request body
            StringEntity reqEntity = new StringEntity("{body}");
            request.setEntity(reqEntity);

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) 
            {
                System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I take the this error:

> {"error":{"code":"BadArgument","message":"Request body is invalid."}}

What can I do for fix it. I didn't find the sample for Create a Person Group with java on the internet, so I can't fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggests, the HTTP request body is malformed as `{body}`.

Please take a look at the [API](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395244) page, under the section labeled **Request body**.  You are required to provide a name, and can optionally add user data.

```
StringEntity reqEntity = new StringEntity("{" +
    "\"name\":\"group1\"," +
    "\"userData\":\"user-provided data attached to the person group\""+
"}")
```

You can find some additional Java examples on the GitHub [SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Face-Android/tree/master/Sample) page.